Unable to get values from Service in Angular
I have created and application with Login Functionality and want to get the logged In user name in the components
Service File:
  login({ username, password }: any): Observable<any> {
if (username === 'admin@gmail.com' && password === 'admin123') {
  this.setToken('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  **this.username1 = username;**
  this.setUserName(username);
  return of({ name: 'Papun Sahoo', email: 'admin@gmail.com' });
}
return throwError(new Error('Failed to login'));

}
On the Component I am trying to access the value
userName?:string;
  constructor(private observer: BreakpointObserver, private router: Router,private loginService: LoginService) {
    **this.userName = this.loginService.getUserName()!;**
    console.log("From Component :"+this.loginService.username1);
  }

but i am getting Undefined here
From Component :undefined
StackBlitz Link to Reproduce
Any help would be appreciated

not an answer, but hard-coding an admin username and password in your code seems like a very bad idea.  You should be hitting an endpoint to get the username and/or authorizations.

Hi @browsermator thanks for pointing out . Actually I am doing this for learning and actual logic will be incorporated.

OK, just remember to never trust the client.  (backend should always check authorization of any request that might need it...)  And of course never rely on obfuscation of code.

What exactly returns undefined? this.loginService.getUserName()?

Hi @SwissCodeMen I was getting in this.loginService.username1

You are providing LoginService twice, once in root via the @Injectable decorator on the service class, and again in AdminModule in the providers array. Removing the LoginService from the providers in AdminModule resolves the issue.
Tip: You can guard against multiple instances of services by injecting the service into itself:
export class LoginService {
  constructor(
    ...
    @Optional() @SkipSelf() private parentLoginService?: LoginService,
  ) {
    if (parentLoginService) {
      throw new Error('Multiple instances of LoginService created!');
    }
  }
  ...
}

EDIT:
To fix page reloading for seemingly no reason, add type="button" to line 22 of your login component:
<button mat-button class="back" type="button" (click)="login()">Login</button>

The type attribute of <button> tags defaults to "submit", which can cause the page to reload.
To avoid this issue in the future, I recommend using the ESLint rule button-has-type.

Hi @MrZane2u thanks for the solution. I have removed it as you suggested and I am still getting undefined(First getting the value and then again getting undefined)
From Comp:admin@gmail.com
......
From Comp:undefined

It seems the page is getting refreshed somehow

@papun The page reload thing was driving me crazy trying to find it, but I finally did. Updating my answer now.

I could be wrong, butI believe it's because setUserName never gets called with the user to match which returns undefined.
